# Why can I not access an element after it has been animated in jQuery and Animate.css?

Tags: jquery, html

I have successfully animated three elements using jQuery but after the animation I can't access them.  I have three images which enter from the right of the VP and doc on the left showing half of the image.  I would like the image to rise to display fully on mouseover.  I have looked through SO and my tutorials on lynda.com and udemy.com to no avail.  Maybe I am being too specific.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    var animationIn = 'animated slideInUp';

    $('#tab1').addClass(animationIn).one(animationEnd, function(){
      $(this).removeClass(animationIn);
      $(this).animate({
        top : '78%',
        left: '10%',
        opacity: .75},
        2000, function() {

        $('#tab2').css({'display': 'block', '-webkit-animation-delay': '2s'}).addClass(animationIn).one(animationEnd, function(){
          $(this).removeClass(animationIn);
          $(this).animate({
            top: '78%',
            left: '22%',
            opacity: .75 },
            2000, function() {

            $('#tab3').css({'display': 'block', '-webkit-animation-delay': '2s'}).addClass(animationIn).one(animationEnd, function(){
              $(this).removeClass(animationIn);
              $(this).animate({
                top: '78%',
                left: '34%',
                opacity: .75
              },2000);
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });

    //I have tried various selector methods 
    $('.header-container').find('#tab1').mouseenter(function() {
      console.log('mouse enter');    
    });

    //I tried the obvious also 
    $('#tab1').mouseenter(function(){
      console.log('mouse enter');
    });
});//end $(docunemt).ready
```

Comment: is it just mouseenter thats not working? do clicks work? i'm wondering if its a delegation issue because youre moving the element around, it thinks the its in a different spot for the enter

Comment: It's both.  I have tried multiple selector filters. I wonder if it has to do with Animate.css...

Comment: I found the culprit.  The parent div has css set to overflow hidden and that was for some reason preventing the div selected by jQuery from responding.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix.  I replaced z-index with opacity .99.  I am using this on top of sibling elements which have a lesser z-index than the parent element.  I have been pulling my hair out about this and finally did what I should have done from the beginning->refer to the docs.  Here is where I found the answer

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index][1]